# Camera not responding

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using the built in camera app in android using intents like this:

```
             final Button Capture=(Button)findViewById(sankalp.jain.sky.R.id.capture);

             Capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri fileUri; 
            final Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            Log.w("intent","for camera");//displayed
            fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
            Log.w("getoutput","getit");//displayed
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name
            Log.w("hello","hello the 2nd step");//displayed

            startActivityForResult(intent,CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

I have implemented the relevant getOutputMediafile() method and the image gets saved in /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Samarth/chart.png
The sdcard is 40MB and there are only 2 files presently totaling some 100KB.

The problem is that the camera works perfectly for some random number of snaps and then randomly hangs and then gives an ANR.
Its totally random,restarting the emulator doesnt work and sometimes it does.

Here is the logcat output

LOGCAT:

```
   I/ActivityManager(   70): Displayed sankalp.jain.sky/.Tabinit: +1s364ms
W/intent  (  596): for camera
D/path    (  596): /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Samarth
W/getoutput(  596): getit
W/hello   (  596): hello the 2nd step
I/ActivityManager(   70): Starting: Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPT
URE cmp=com.android.camera/.Camera (has extras) } from pid 596
D/PhoneWindow(  596): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused vie
w com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4056d7e0 has no id.
I/WindowManager(   70): Setting rotation to 1, animFlags=1
I/ActivityManager(   70): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US tou
ch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=2 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=13}
V/CameraHolder(  411): open camera 0
D/CameraHardwareStub(   34): initHeapLocked: preview size=320x240
I/StagefrightPlayer(   34): setDataSource('/system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.o
gg')
I/StagefrightPlayer(   34): setDataSource('/system/media/audio/ui/VideoRecord.og
g')
D/Camera  (  411): app passed NULL surface
D/CameraHardwareStub(   34): initHeapLocked: preview size=320x240
V/camera  (  411): startPreview
I/ActivityManager(   70): Displayed com.android.camera/.Camera: +1s198ms
W/OrientationEventListener(  411): Cannot detect sensors. Not enabled
E/SurfaceFlinger(   70): texture=10, using format 17, which is not supported by
the GL
V/GLRootView(  411): onSurfaceChanged: 627x470, gl10: com.google.android.gles_jn
i.GLImpl@40511140
V/GLRootView(  411): layout content pane 627x470
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(  596): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
D/dalvikvm(   70): GC_EXPLICIT freed 130K, 47% free 4929K/9159K, external 3511K/
4385K, paused 795ms
V/camera  (  411): Start autofocus.
D/dalvikvm(  411): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 34K, 51% free 2932K/5895K, external 2
480K/2565K, paused 697ms
V/camera  (  411): mAutoFocusTime = 1622ms
V/camera  (  411): doSnap: mFocusState=3
D/CameraHardwareStub(   34): initHeapLocked: preview size=320x240
D/dalvikvm(  596): GC_EXPLICIT freed 209K, 49% free 2870K/5575K, external 3065K/
3507K, paused 650ms
D/SntpClient(   70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address fami
ly not supported by protocol
I/InputDispatcher(   70): Application is not responding: Window{40751af8 com.and
roid.camera/com.android.camera.Camera paused=false}.  5014.6ms since event, 5014
.0ms since wait started
I/WindowManager(   70): Input event dispatching timed out sending to com.android
.camera/com.android.camera.Camera
I/Process (   70): Sending signal. PID: 411 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  411): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  411): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process (   70): Sending signal. PID: 70 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(   70): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(   70): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process (   70): Sending signal. PID: 340 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  340): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  340): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process (   70): Sending signal. PID: 115 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  115): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  115): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
D/dalvikvm(   70): GC_EXPLICIT freed 354K, 45% free 5052K/9159K, external 3511K/
4385K, paused 157ms
E/ActivityManager(   70): ANR in com.android.camera (com.android.camera/.Camera)

E/ActivityManager(   70): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
E/ActivityManager(   70): Load: 0.12 / 0.23 / 0.25
E/ActivityManager(   70): CPU usage from 42677ms to 0ms ago:
E/ActivityManager(   70):   0.3% 70/system_server: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / fau
lts: 5 minor
E/ActivityManager(   70):   0.3% 115/com.android.systemui: 0.2% user + 0% kernel
 / faults: 4 minor
E/ActivityManager(   70):   0.1% 340/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel / fa
ults: 4 minor
E/ActivityManager(   70):   0% 34/mediaserver: 0% user + 0% kernel
E/ActivityManager(   70):   0% 32/rild: 0% user + 0% kernel
E/ActivityManager(   70):   0% 41/adbd: 0% user + 0% kernel
E/ActivityManager(   70): 1.1% TOTAL: 0.7% user + 0.4% kernel
E/ActivityManager(   70): CPU usage from 1031ms to 1675ms later:
E/ActivityManager(   70):   10% 70/system_server: 6.2% user + 4.6% kernel
E/ActivityManager(   70):     10% 100/InputDispatcher: 7.8% user + 3.1% kernel
E/ActivityManager(   70): 34% TOTAL: 17% user + 17% kernel
I/InputDispatcher(   70): Dropping event because the pointer is not down.
D/dalvikvm(  115): GC_CONCURRENT freed 365K, 49% free 2977K/5831K, external 2169
K/2674K, paused 9ms+6ms
D/SntpClient(   70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address fami
ly not supported by protocol
W/ProcessStats(   70): Skipping unknown process pid 734
W/ProcessStats(   70): Skipping unknown process pid 735
V/BackupManagerService(   70): Backup requested but nothing pending
D/SntpClient(   70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address fami
ly not supported by protocol
I/EventLogService(  266): Aggregate from 1332336498594 (log), 1332336498594 (dat
a)
D/dalvikvm(  266): GC_EXPLICIT freed 61K, 55% free 3085K/6727K, external 1625K/2
137K, paused 296ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I could never figure out the reason myself but due to some problems when I decided to upgrade the emulator to Google API15(from API10) the camera doesn't hang anymore.
Upgrading also rectified some weird problems like

[Force portrait mode in camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908387/force-portrait-mode-in-camera)

Hope that helps someone.