# Android Camera giving rotated captured image in some devices

Tags: android, camera, rotation

When I capture Image I get the captured image rotated.

I am setting the rotation on Camera Parameters object.

> Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
>   params.setRotation(90);

**But its not working. I have tried setting the rotation angle to 0, 90, 270 and 360, but there is no change in the captured image rotation.**
 **Device : Redmi Note 5**. 
**Working fine for other devices**, i.e. setting a rotation angle of 90 degrees makes the image rotated in original orientation.

The least I expect is at least there must be a rotation change when I change the value of rotation angle to different degrees. But that doesn't seem to have any impact.

**Original Image**
[image: Original Image]

**Camera Captured Image**
[image: Camera Captured Image]

I have done

> mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(rotate);
>   It changes the camera preview rotation but doesn't change the captured image rotation.

Also, I have seen the following posts, tried solutions but haven't found any working solution.

[Android camera unexplainable rotation on capture for some devices (not in EXIF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852154/android-camera-unexplainable-rotation-on-capture-for-some-devices-not-in-exif)

[Why does an image captured using camera intent gets rotated on some devices on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-does-an-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-on-a)

[setRotation(90) to take picture in portrait mode does not work on samsung devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023696/setrotation90-to-take-picture-in-portrait-mode-does-not-work-on-samsung-device)

[Android - Camera preview is sideways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841122/android-camera-preview-is-sideways/5110406)

[Force a camera to always open in portrait mode in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259299/force-a-camera-to-always-open-in-portrait-mode-in-android/10259572#10259572)

[Android Camera in Portrait on SurfaceView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543059/android-camera-in-portrait-on-surfaceview/6762941#6762941)

[Android - Capture photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491961/android-capture-photo)

[Force portrait mode in camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908387/force-portrait-mode-in-camera)

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this same issue. i have try this one and work fine for me.

```
private CameraSource.PictureCallback mPicture = new CameraSource.PictureCallback() {
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes) {
   int orientation = Exif.getOrientation(bytes);
   Bitmap   bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
   switch(orientation) {
       case 90:
           bitmapPicture= rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
           break;
       case 180:
           bitmapPicture= rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
           break;
       case 270:
           bitmapPicture= rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
           break;
       case 0:
           // if orientation is zero we don't need to rotate this
       default:
           break;
   }
   //write your code here to save bitmap 
   }
}

public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
  }
```

Below class is used to get orientation from byte[] data.

```
public class Exif {
private static final String TAG = "CameraExif";

// Returns the degrees in clockwise. Values are 0, 90, 180, or 270.
public static int getOrientation(byte[] jpeg) {
    if (jpeg == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    int offset = 0;
    int length = 0;

    // ISO/IEC 10918-1:1993(E)
    while (offset + 3 < jpeg.length && (jpeg[offset++] & 0xFF) == 0xFF) {
        int marker = jpeg[offset] & 0xFF;

        // Check if the marker is a padding.
        if (marker == 0xFF) {
            continue;
        }
        offset++;

        // Check if the marker is SOI or TEM.
        if (marker == 0xD8 || marker == 0x01) {
            continue;
        }
        // Check if the marker is EOI or SOS.
        if (marker == 0xD9 || marker == 0xDA) {
            break;
        }

        // Get the length and check if it is reasonable.
        length = pack(jpeg, offset, 2, false);
        if (length < 2 || offset + length > jpeg.length) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid length");
            return 0;
        }

        // Break if the marker is EXIF in APP1.
        if (marker == 0xE1 && length >= 8 &&
                pack(jpeg, offset + 2, 4, false) == 0x45786966 &&
                pack(jpeg, offset + 6, 2, false) == 0) {
            offset += 8;
            length -= 8;
            break;
        }

        // Skip other markers.
        offset += length;
        length = 0;
    }

    // JEITA CP-3451 Exif Version 2.2
    if (length > 8) {
        // Identify the byte order.
        int tag = pack(jpeg, offset, 4, false);
        if (tag != 0x49492A00 && tag != 0x4D4D002A) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid byte order");
            return 0;
        }
        boolean littleEndian = (tag == 0x49492A00);

        // Get the offset and check if it is reasonable.
        int count = pack(jpeg, offset + 4, 4, littleEndian) + 2;
        if (count < 10 || count > length) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid offset");
            return 0;
        }
        offset += count;
        length -= count;

        // Get the count and go through all the elements.
        count = pack(jpeg, offset - 2, 2, littleEndian);
        while (count-- > 0 && length >= 12) {
            // Get the tag and check if it is orientation.
            tag = pack(jpeg, offset, 2, littleEndian);
            if (tag == 0x0112) {
                // We do not really care about type and count, do we?
                int orientation = pack(jpeg, offset + 8, 2, littleEndian);
                switch (orientation) {
                    case 1:
                        return 0;
                    case 3:
                        return 180;
                    case 6:
                        return 90;
                    case 8:
                        return 270;
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Unsupported orientation");
                return 0;
            }
            offset += 12;
            length -= 12;
        }
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "Orientation not found");
    return 0;
}

private static int pack(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length, boolean littleEndian) {
    int step = 1;
    if (littleEndian) {
        offset += length - 1;
        step = -1;
    }

    int value = 0;
    while (length-- > 0) {
        value = (value << 8) | (bytes[offset] & 0xFF);
        offset += step;
    }
    return value;
}
}
```

i am facing this issue into few device like Vivo, MI.
Hear i have spend two days after that i have resolved this issue.
Thank you.